# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar o no un objeto que creo en OpenGL con C++ al presionar una tecla?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, opengl

tengo un problema, porque tengo que crear un programa que visualice los ejes de coordenadas y un cubo (OpenGL y Microsoft Visual Studio), hasta aquí bien. Pero después tengo que crear de alguna forma una funcionalidad y es que cuando presione una tecla, los ejes de coordenadas se escondan o no. Tengo lo siguiente:

Cabecera de la clase:

```
#ifndef __CGVINTERFACE
#define __CGVINTERFACE

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cgvInterface {
    protected:
        // Attributes
        int width_window; // initial width of the display window
        int height_window;  // initial height of the display window

        // TODO: Practice 1: Declare the boolean variable to control whether the axes are visualized or not.  
        bool axes = true;
    public:
        // Default constructor and destructor
        cgvInterface();
        ~cgvInterface();

        // Static methods
        // event callbacks
        static void set_glutKeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y); // method to control keyboard events
        static void set_glutReshapeFunc(int w, int h); // method to define the camera and the viewport
                                                       // it is automatically called when the window is resized
        static void set_glutDisplayFunc(); // method to render the scene


        // Methods
        // initialize all the parameters to create a display window
        void configure_environment(int argc, char** argv, // main parameters
                                   int _width_window, int _height_window, // width and height of the display window
                                   int _pos_X, int _pos_Y, // init position of the display window
                                                     string _title // title of the display window
                                                     ); 
        void init_callbacks(); // init all the callbacks

        void init_rendering_loop(); // render the scene and wait for an event in the interface

        // methods get_ and set_ to access the attributes
        int get_width_window(){return width_window;};
        int get_height_window(){return height_window;};

        void set_width_window(int _width_window){width_window = _width_window;};
        void set_height_window(int _height_window){height_window = _height_window;};

        // TODO: practice 1: specify the corresponding methods get_axes() and set_axes() to get the value of the boolean variable axes and to set it, respctively.  
        void set_axes(bool *axes);
        bool get_axes();

};

#endif
```

Y este es su implementación:

```
    #include <cstdlib>

#include "cgvInterface.h"

extern cgvInterface interface; // the callbacks must be static and this object is required to access to the variables of the class                   // ellos a las variables de la clase

// Constructor and destructor methods -----------------------------------

cgvInterface::cgvInterface () {
    // TODO: Practice 1: Initialize the variable 'axes' to TRUE. 
    axes = true;
}

cgvInterface::~cgvInterface () {}


// Public methods ----------------------------------------

void cgvInterface::configure_environment(int argc, char** argv, 
                                   int _width_window, int _height_window, 
                                   int _pos_X, int _pos_Y, 
                                                     string _title)
                                                     {
    // initialization of the interface variables                                                                    
    width_window = _width_window;
    height_window = _height_window;

    // initialization of the display window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(_width_window,_height_window);
  glutInitWindowPosition(_pos_X,_pos_Y);
    glutCreateWindow(_title.c_str());

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable the removal of hidden surfaces by using the z-buffer
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0); // define the background color of the window

}

void cgvInterface::init_rendering_loop() {
    glutMainLoop(); // initialize the visualization loop of OpenGL
}

void cgvInterface::set_glutKeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
  switch (key) {
// TODO: practice 1: Add the code to enable/disable the visualization of the axes after pressing 'a'. 
    case 'a':
        if (interface.get_axes() == true)
        {
            bool axes = true;
            interface.set_axes(&axes);
        }
        else
        {
            bool axes = false;
            interface.set_axes(&axes);
        }
        break;
    case 27: // Escape key to exit
      exit(1);
    break;
  }
    glutPostRedisplay(); // renew the content of the window
}

void cgvInterface::set_glutReshapeFunc(int w, int h) {
  // dimension of the viewport with a new width and a new height of the display window 
  glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei) w,(GLsizei) h);

  // store the new values of the viewport and the display window. 
  interface.set_width_window(w);
  interface.set_height_window(h);

  // Set up the kind of projection to be used
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,200);

  // it defines the camera
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(1.5,1.0,2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

void cgvInterface::set_glutDisplayFunc() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the window and the depth buffer
  glPushMatrix(); // store the model matrix

  // TODO: Practice 1: Draw the axis
  if (interface.get_axes() == true)
  {
      glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red x
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
      // x aix

      glVertex3f(-4.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(4.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);

      // arrow
      glVertex3f(4.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(3.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);

      glVertex3f(4.0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(3.0, -1.0f, 0.0f);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();

      // y 
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // green y
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex3f(0.0, -4.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0, 4.0f, 0.0f);

      // arrow
      glVertex3f(0.0, 4.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0, 3.0f, 0.0f);

      glVertex3f(0.0, 4.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0, 3.0f, 0.0f);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();

      // z 
      glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // blue z
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0f, -4.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0f, 4.0f);

      // arrow
      glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0f, 4.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0f, 3.0f);

      glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0f, 4.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0, -1.0f, 3.0f);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();
  }
  // TODO: Practice 1: draw the object of the scene
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutWireCube(1);


  glPopMatrix (); // restore the model matrix
  glutSwapBuffers(); // it is used instead of glFlush(), in case of double buffer, to avoid flickering
}

bool cgvInterface::get_axes()
{
    return axes;
}

void cgvInterface::set_axes(bool *axes)
{
    if (*axes == true)
        *axes = false;
    else
        *axes = true;
}

void cgvInterface::init_callbacks() {
    glutKeyboardFunc(set_glutKeyboardFunc);
    glutReshapeFunc(set_glutReshapeFunc);
    glutDisplayFunc(set_glutDisplayFunc);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando pulse la tecla "a", desaparezcan los ejes? (En el que he puesto no desaparecen.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El render no funciona como crees, para dejar de ver un objeto simplemente debes omitir la llamada a su pintado, así que no hay que "hacer desaparecer los ejes".

Comment: Claro, eso lo he entendido, y es lo que hago, por eso, dentro de la función "set_glutKeyboardFunc" está el switch para que cuando presione la tecla a, cambie el valor bool de axes a true o false y a final de dicha función, se ejecuta "glutPostRedisplay();" que lo que hace es volver a pintar todo. Pero en "set_glutDisplayFunc()" que es la función que pinta tanto los ejes como el cubo, tengo un condicional que comprueba si la variable axes está a true o false y dependiendo de su valor, se ejecuta el pintado o no. Pero no funciona y no sé cómo hacer que funcione :S

Comment: ¡Pues no me extraña que estés confundido! El código es tremendamente confuso. ¿Se llega a llamar la función `set_glutKeyboardFunc`? ¿Por qué no estableces el valor de `cgvInterface` directamente en lugar de hacer **tantos** líos con punteros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu código funciona (lo cuál es difícil de asumir porque es muy confuso) tu función para establecer el flag de pintado (`void cgvInterface::set_axes(bool *)`) no hace lo que crees que hace.

Veamos dónde es llamada:

```
void cgvInterface::set_glutKeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
  switch (key) {

    case 'a':
        if (interface.get_axes() == true)
        {
            bool axes = true;
            interface.set_axes(&axes);
        }
        else
        {
            bool axes = false;
            interface.set_axes(&axes);
        }
        break;
    case 27: // Escape key to exit
      exit(1);
    break;
  }
    glutPostRedisplay(); // renew the content of the window
}
```

La variable `bool cgvInterface::axes` nace con un valor `true`<sup>1</sup>; así que la primera vez que se pulsa `'a'` la sentencia `interface.get_axes() == true` será verdadera y ejecutaremos `set_axes` pasándole un puntero a un booleano que contiene `true`, veamos esa función:

```
void cgvInterface::set_axes(bool *axes)
{
    if (*axes == true)
        *axes = false;
    else
        *axes = true;
}
```

Dado que el puntero booleano proveído contiene `true` **el mismo booleano proveído** pasará a `false` y la variable miembro `bool cgvInterface::axes` permanecerá inalterada con valor `true`. Seguramente lo que querías hacer era esto:

1. Declara `set_axes` para recibir un simple booleano:

   ```
   void set_axes(bool value);
   ```
2. Establece el valor de `cgvInterface::axes` al valor recibido en `set_axes`:

   ```
   void cgvInterface::set_axes(bool value)
   {
       axes = value;
   }
   ```
3. Simplifica `void cgvInterface::set_glutKeyboardFunc`:

   ```
   void cgvInterface::set_glutKeyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
       interface.set_axes(key == 'a');
       if (key == 27) exit(1);
       glutPostRedisplay(); // renew the content of the window
   }
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>Después ese valor `true` es re-escrito sin motivo, en el constructor `cgvInterface::cgvInterface ()`, puedes eliminar este constructor pues no hace nada.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!! Ya le he arreglado y funciona!

Comment: Eso que pides dependerá de la manera en que se gestiona el teclado (cosa que no has indicado). Necesitas atender a el pulsado y soltado de tecla en lugar de atender a si la tecla está o no pulsada.